# IOS "Audio" Background Mode

Tags: ios

I have a quick question, does anyone knows of any other way in iOS 9 and above, to be able for an app to access the microphone in background, except to use the "Audio" Background Mode?

Also the app is not recording the audio, it is just processing in order to try and recognize the audio that is received through the microphone, and to provide notification to the user.

I am asking this question, since I have used "Audio Background Mode" in version 1 of the app, and continued using "Audio Background Mode" in version 2 (update), but when i try to submit the version 2 to App store, they are rejecting it and explaining that App Version 2, is not in compliance of 2.16 because recording audio is not proper use of Audio Background Mode, and i am not recording audio.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: could you explain "it is just processing in order to try and recognize the audio that is received through the microphone"

Comment: the audio is not stored anywhere except in a buffer as it is received and the audio is checked for a secret code, to try and recognize it. It is audio recognition app.

Comment: You dont necessarily need to record, I had an app that warn user when a baby cries, and it did not record the sound, just pick the volume of the noise and the time...so, Audio background mode seems to works fine for your description.

Comment: Hi UlyssesR i know that Audio Background Mode works fine for my description, i am just asking if there is any other way to achieve the same, "The use of the microphone while the app is in background" without selecting the Audio Background Mode on the app config, since Apple is saying that my app is out of compliance.

Comment: Just out of curiosity: why do you need it? From your description, your app does use microphone in background, so I don't see any troubles with just adding a couple of lines in Info.plist.

Comment: xinatanil, can you please explain what you mean?
The issue is that i have the "Audio Background Mode" enabled and the app works without problem, but when i try to send the update to Apple, they are rejecting the update since it is not in compliance with Background Modes.

Comment: so i decided to check here, if there is any other way, that i dont know of, to be able to achieve the same functionality, to use the microphone in the backround and to try and recognize audio.

Answer (score 1):

You can't achieve what you want without adding 'audio' value for UIBackgroundModes key. The media framework uses this value to prevent app being suspended when it's going in background.

From what you say your app is falling into: `Audio recording apps` category. So, Apple have no reason to reject your app. Try to contact App Review team or in iTunes Connect in `App Review Information` there is a `Notes` field where you can provide additional information used by review team, write there some explanations of how your app works in background.

Comment: Azimov, i am trying to avoid enabling this background mode, since Apple doesnt approve my update of the app for 2 months now, just because saying the app is not in compliance with 2.16

Comment: Since i know for my 2 years developing in IOS, that there is no other way to achieve this functionality, but i guess i wanted to check here, where there are more experienced developers, if maybe i missed something and that there is another way to achieve this same functionality.

Comment: @BorceIvanovski check my updated answer, maybe it helps

Comment: hahahaha azimov, thanks for the information, but i explained 10 times in messages and 2 times on the phone to the person from App Review Team, and still the same answer. I also send appeal, which was rejected in very short time as well.

Comment: that's really sad. Btw can you show/explain some implementation details of you app related to processing feature ?

Comment: Azimov do you think this would be enough explanation for them "Thanks for the reply, but as we discussed earlier as well, "ALLeVIEW" is not recording audio it is just listening. The audio received through the Microphone while the app is in the background, is not saved or stored anywhere, the app is just processing the audio , in order to provide notification to the user that Audio has been recognized and provide the necessary information regarding the recognized audio to the user. " and also i have provided them with links where to find audio, to test the app as well. You think this is enough?

Comment: yes of course i can, just give me few min to go to my Mac

Comment: i will try to explain it in simple, if you want i can show you implementation.
For each byte in the buffer, i am sending it to be checked to outside API, and if the api returns recognized i get the information what is being recognized, and then provide the same information to the user. I believe it is like this implemented, have to check exactly the code, since i inherited the development of the app and i havent really implemented this part of the app but have looked at it. I just continued development on new features.

Comment: I think your explanation is ok. I worked 2 years ago on similar project as yours and basically it was doing what you are describing. We also weren't storing the sounds obtained by micro just sent some bytes to a server which processed them (app was released on the store). A workaround would be to store sounds on the device but after a while to delete them.

Comment: yeah but still Apple wont allow the background mode to be enabled either way. so this is why i thought let me put a message here and check maybe there is a new way in IOS 9 or later, that this can be achieved.

Answer (score 1):

You're saying that you're app has access to microphone in background, right? System doesn't know if you're recording audio or just processing audio, and it doesn't matter because the mere fact that you have access to microphone in background is already enough.

Your app has to tell the system explicitly that it will use some features in the background. Why?

> Declaring the services lets the system know which services you use,
>   but in some cases it is the system frameworks that actually prevent
>   your application from being suspended.
>   https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH4-SW23

I.e. if your app doesn't declare that it will use microphone in the background, the system will simply suspend your app because it thinks that there's no need for your app to be active. If your app gets into the App Store in the current state, your app may get suspended in the background (when it really shouldn't), which leads to bad user experience.
So, I think, there's no way you will get into the App Store without explicitly declaring that your app uses microphone in the background.

How can you do that?

> Support for some types of background execution must be declared in
>   advance by the app that uses them. In Xcode 5 and later, you declare
>   the background modes your app supports from the Capabilities tab of
>   your project settings. Enabling the Background Modes option adds the
>   UIBackgroundModes key to your app’s Info.plist file. Selecting one or
>   more checkboxes adds the corresponding background mode values to that
>   key. Table 3-1 lists the background modes you can specify and the
>   values that Xcode assigns to the UIBackgroundModes key in your app’s
>   Info.plist file.

I hope this answers your question.

Comment: xinatanil, i understand all that you just wrote, and sorry that i made you write it, and i agree with you the app must have the Audio Background mode on, so the system knows not to suspend it, and also for users not to have bad experience. I was just curiously asking, if there is any other way to achieve the same, since Apple has been rejecting my update for the past 2 months and saying that my app is not in compliance with the 2.16 (Use of Background Modes)

Comment: I already have the Audio Background Modes enabled when i first released version 1 of the app, and that one went through without any issues. We are doing an update of the app, with newer functionality, and this is when Apple is telling me that my update is not in compliance with 2.16

Comment: So, you're telling that you enabled Audio Background Modes in 1.0, removed it in 2.0, despite still using microphone in background?

Comment: no, i enabled background mode in 1.0, i left background mode enabled in 2.0 and Apple is rejecting update 2.0 because it is not in compliance with 2.16

Comment: Okay, thanks for additional information. You should definitely update your question because without this information, your question is very misleading. 2.16 says "Multitasking Apps may only use background services for their intended purposes: VoIP, audio playback, location, task completion, local notifications, etc.". Do you use microphone for something else than audio processing in the background? Shazam does basically the same thing, I see no reason for your app to be rejected. Could you please explain why exactly your app is being rejected?

Comment: hahahahha xinatanil, exactly what i told the person from App Review Team last night, to which replied "well your app we find it not in compliance". No i dont use it for anything else, except for this specific functionality, nothing hidden nothing else at all, just the same functionality as shazam and other apps that does the same. That is all i am getting as answer, your app is not in compliance with 2.16 LOL they are saying recording is not appropriate use of Background Mode, where i have told them that the app does not record audio, just process it